# WooCommerce не добавляется товар в корзину у не авторизованных пользователей

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт, под который разрабатывалась тема, и тестировалась она всегда авторизованными пользователями. То есть у авторизованного пользователя всё работает. А вот если не авторизоваться то товары не добавляются в корзину, то есть он туда попадает но если перейти на любую другую страницу то корзина пустая, а если добавить другой товар, то в корзине будет лежать только он один.

Код который добавляет товар в корзину:

```
if (isset($_POST['product']) && !empty($_POST['product'])) {
    $product_id = $_POST['product']['id'];
    $quantity = $_POST['product']['quantity'];
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);

}

if (isset($_POST['product_update']) && !empty($_POST['product_update'])) {
    $product_key = $_POST['product_update']['key'];
    $quantity = $_POST['product_update']['quantity'];
    WC()->cart->set_quantity($product_key, $quantity);
}

if (isset($_POST['product_remove']) && !empty($_POST['product_remove'])) {
    $product_key = $_POST['product_remove'];
    WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($product_key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно что у тебя не работают сессии и куки для не авторизованных, поэтому Корзина и не помнит что ты в неё положил после перехода на другую страницу. Копай в эту сторону в общем.

Comment: Про сессии и куки это понятно, я уже все файлы перешарил которые влияют на куки и ничего не нашёл... Если ставить шаблон который ставит WooCommerce всё работает

Comment: Поищи по дефолтной теме куски кода с упоминанием кук и сессий и смотри почему аналогичных кусков нет в твоей самодельной теме.

Answer (score 0):

Путём более правильного гугления, нашёл таки ответ на свой вопрос, как выяснилось не я один такой=(

Необходимо добавить для не авторизованных пользователей вызов функции `WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);`

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
    WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
}
```

В файл темы **functions.php**

Решение на [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add_to_cart-function-not-adding-to-cart-when-logged-out/#post-6036622)

Вопрос считаю закрытым